# Apollo GraphQL client resolvers not resolving unless server value is specified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am doing some fairly complex stuff with my Apollo GraphQL client. So far it has been great, but there is one annoying issue I am working through. I tried to set up some resolvers asynchronously (the resolvers depend on some other async app state). I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but here is some relevant code:

Apollo client setup:

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPH_NODE_URI
  }),
  resolvers,
  typeDefs
});

const defaults = {
  loggedInUser: "",
  guildBankValue: "0",
  shareValue: "0",
  totalShares: "0",
  currentPeriod: "0",
  exchangeRate: "0",
  proposalQueueLength: "0",
  totalPoolShares: "0",
  poolValue: "0",
  poolShareValue: "0"
}
cache.writeData({
  data: { ...defaults, loggedInUser: window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser") || "" }
});
```

Function to generate client side resolvers:

```js
function getLocalResolvers(medianizer, moloch, molochPool, token) {
  return {
    Query: {
      guildBankValue: async () => {
        const value = (await token.balanceOf(process.env.REACT_APP_GUILD_BANK_ADDRESS)).toString();
        return value
      },
      totalShares: async () => {
        const shares = (await moloch.totalShares()).toString();
        return shares
      },
      currentPeriod: async () => {
        const period = (await moloch.getCurrentPeriod()).toString();
        return period
      },
      exchangeRate: async () => {
        const rate = (await medianizer.compute())[0];
        return utils.bigNumberify(rate).toString();
      },
      proposalQueueLength: async () => {
        const length = (await moloch.getProposalQueueLength()).toString();
        return length
      },
      totalPoolShares: async () => {
        const shares = (await molochPool.totalPoolShares()).toString()
        return shares
      },
      poolValue: async () => {
        const value = (await token.balanceOf(process.env.REACT_APP_MOLOCH_POOL_ADDRESS)).toString()
        return value
      },
    }
  };
}
```

App entry point where I add the resolvers:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    restored: false,
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    // await persistor.restore();
    await this.populateData(true);
    this.setState({ restored: true });
  }

  async populateData(refetch) {
    let {
      data: { loggedInUser }
    } = await client.query({
      query: IS_LOGGED_IN
    });

    // make sure logged in metamask user is the one that's saved to storage
    if (loggedInUser) {
      await initWeb3(client);
    }

    const medianizer = await getMedianizer(loggedInUser);
    const moloch = await getMoloch();
    const molochPool = await getMolochPool();
    const token = await getToken();

    client.addResolvers(getLocalResolvers(medianizer, moloch, molochPool, token))
```

Render method of App component:

```js
render() {
    const { restored } = this.state;
    return restored ? (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
          <Query query={IS_LOGGED_IN}>
            {loggedInUserData => {
              return (
                <>
                  <Background />
                  <Header loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} client={client} populateData={this.populateData} />
                  <Wrapper>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        render={props => <Home {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/proposals"
                        render={props => <ProposalList {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/members"
                        render={props => <MemberList {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/proposalsubmission"
                        render={props =>
                          loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser ? (
                            <ProposalSubmission {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />
                          ) : (
                            <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/" }} />
                          )
                        }
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/pool"
                        component={props => <Pool {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />}
                      />
                      <Route
                        path="/pool-members"
                        render={props => (
                          <PoolMemberListView {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />
                        )}
                      />
                      <Route
                        component={props => <Home {...props} loggedInUser={loggedInUserData.data.loggedInUser} pageQueriesLoading={!restored} />}
                      />
                    </Switch>
                  </Wrapper>
                  <ToastMessage.Provider ref={node => (window.toastProvider = node)} />
                </>
              );
            }}
          </Query>
        </Router>
      </ApolloProvider>
    ) : (
      <>
        <Background />
        <Dimmer active>
          <Loader size="massive" />
        </Dimmer>
      </>
    );
  }
```

The issue I am facing is that when I load my homepage (`/` route), the resolvers do not fire, I just get the default values. When I navigate to another page in my app, the resolvers actually do fire, then I can go back to my home page and see the updated data. I am lost on why this is happening. If I go directly to the `/pool` route, the app loads with the right data.

The project is open source, so feel free to look at the source: https://github.com/MolochVentures/moloch-monorepo/tree/resolvers

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Removed apollo-link-state package and updated client setup code, same thing is happening.

Edit2: Extremely weird, I found that the resolvers call properly if I add a non-client value to the GraphQL query i.e.:

```js
// this query works
const GET_POOL_METADATA = gql`
  {
    poolValue @client
    exchangeRate @client
    proposals(first: 1, where: { processed: true }, orderBy: proposalIndex, orderDirection: desc) {
      proposalIndex
    }
    totalShares @client
    guildBankValue @client
  }
`;

// this one doesnt
const GET_POOL_METADATA = gql`
  {
    poolValue @client
    exchangeRate @client
    totalShares @client
    guildBankValue @client
  }
`;
```

I will change the title to reflect this.

Comment: apollo-link-state is [deprecated](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#migrating-from-apollo-link-state) since Apollo Client now has built-in local state management. I would suggest migrating to the new API and reviewing the docs carefully

Comment: Thank you will do this. They still have a big section on using apollo-link-state unfortunately.

Comment: @DanielRearden I migrated to the new API, still having the same issue.

Comment: @rhlsthrm Did you manage to figure this one out? I'm looking to add async resolvers to my app but I'll renounce them if it's such a hassle

Comment: The workaround I mentioned does work @PaulRazvanBerg, you just have to put a non-client field in as part of the query.